# Git commit error after using Git Husky and esLint

Tags: eslint

It can be submitted normally without configuration using Husky. After using Hushy, an error will be reported directly when committing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjJa5.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB1O3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjJa5.png)

Comment: Who can help me? Githhusky and eslint are configured, but they can't work properly.

Comment: Can you run this command `node --version` in your terminal and paste the output here?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with executing the pre commit hook. Which is located in `.git/hooks/pre-commit*`

Since the second line of your screenshot says `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command` you should first try to add node to your `PATH` variable.